# Add the search box to the bottom menu in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Add the search box to the bottom menu in Magento 2 ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can copy below code from Header and Put it inside Footer.

**app/code/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
```

after that you can move that block according to your requirement.

For Example (in your case),

```
<move element="top.search" destination="footer-newsletter" after="form-subscribe" />
```

Hope it helps :)